# Webmaster Blog?

Tags: discussion, activity, blog

Given how new webmaster tools are frequently released, and how search engines update their algorithms regularly, and how the field of being a webmaster is always changing, I thought that it might be nice to have a webmaster blog to keep track of all those updates. It would also help [increase our activity](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/633/what-can-be-done-to-get-webmasters-more-popular-in-2012).

See [this page](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/06/blog-overflow) for instructions on how we could get started.

Comment: Nice idea. I haven't the time or inspiration to write for it though.

Comment: If we could round up some ideas for posts perhaps we could write one each - perhaps each entry could have a link through to frequently asked questions and an accompanying community wiki answer?

Comment: @toomanyairmiles the blog would probably be about google updating it's algorithm, and other current events in the webmaster world. Though we could have a question of the week feature, and other stuff as well.

Comment: @toomanyairmiles: http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/621/soliciting-ideas-for-monthly-topics-2012

If we used the topics discussed there for content while nothing is really going on in the web world, it might inspire a few people to write articles. I might write one or two.

Comment: @Christopher yes, that sounds like a good idea, if we could list out a few in a meta question people could jump in for an assignment

Comment: @Christopher if your interested in writing articles, could you add your name to the list in the cw question below?

Comment: @toomanyairmiles would you be interested in writing an article too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this page: http://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/. Feel free to edit this.

### Define the scope and purpose of the blog.

This blog will cover the same topics discussed on webmasters.se.

#### What will this blog be about

- search engine algorithm updates
- cool new tools that are released
- question of the week/month
- Interviews with active users of webmasters.se
- an article about designing for humans, not search engines (http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3582587#3582587)
- webmasters.se news (from chat)
- what's on topic and off topic on this site - e.g. HTML offtopic, detailed servers stuff, offtopic, SEO - ontopic
- how name registration and dns work to help with tracking down problems
- tracking down htaccess problems
- how to create, administer, and deploy site updates without downtime
- **add your ideas to this list.** Here is a good list that we can work off of: [Soliciting Ideas for Monthly Topics - 2012](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/621/soliciting-ideas-for-monthly-topics-2012)

### Recruit contributors

- christofian
- Christopher
- paulmorriss (expressed interest in chat)
- danlefree
- **add your name to this list if your interested in writing for this blog**

### Plan a schedule.

I think that once a week is reasonable. Mayby more, if a lot of people are interested in writing posts for the blog, or if there is a lot of news.

### Chat Room

[I created a chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2600/webmasters-blog) so we can talk about the blog. feel free to use it.